# Python Error in else syntax

Tags: python

I have the following python code:

```
def myFunction(myDictionary, query):
    D=set() 
    for i in range(len(query)):
        if query[i] in myDictionary.keys():
            if i==0:
                D.update((myDictionary[query[i]])
            else:
                D.intersection_update(myDictionary[query[i]])
    return D
```

`myDictionary` contains dictionary items as follows: `{'first':{0,1,2}, 'second':{5,2,1}, ..etc}`. The query contains a l list of words, e.g. `['first','second',..ect,]`
I want to return the intersection of all the `query` words. For example, if `query=['first','second']` and `myDictionary={'first':{0,1,2}, 'second':{5,2,1}}`, then my result set should be the intersection which is: `{1,2}`.

When I run my code, I get a syntax error in the else statement. I added `if i==0` because otherwise my result set `D` will always be empty set. I do not see what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing parethesis:

```
D.update((myDictionary[query[i]])
# 2 open ^ but only one close ---^
```

Python cannot detect the missing parenthesis until the next line, where the `else:` statement is unexpected.

You only need one pair of parenthesis there:

```
D.update(myDictionary[query[i]])
```

You also do not need to call `.keys()` to do a membership test on a dictionary:

```
if query[i] in myDictionary:
```

is enough.

You probably want to loop *directly* over the `query` list and use `enumerate()` instead:

```
for i, q in enumerate(query):
    if q in myDictionary:
        if not i:
            D.update(myDictionary[q])
        else:
            D.intersection_update(myDictionary[q])
```

or switch to using a generator expression:

```
def myFunction(myDictionary, query):
    matches = (myDictionary[q] for q in myDictionary.viewkeys() & query)
    try:
        D = {next(matches)}  # start with the first match
    except StopIteration:
        # Nothing matched
        return set()
    D.intersection_update(*matches)
    return D
```

Use `.keys()` if you are using Python 3; `.viewkeys()` in Python 2 and `.keys()` in Python 3 return [dictionary view objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) which, for keys at least, act like sets.